# Load JavaScript shared-library at startup of mongod

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shared-libraries

How can I load a JavaScript library as shared-library into mongodb when I start mongod process?

I could not find a solution when searching the internet. What I searched for so far was:

- Is there a hook method that I can use, so I could `load(...)` my library at startup?
- Can I pass a JavaScript library to `mongod` process at startup?
- Can I pass a JavaScript library in the config file of mongodb at startup?

I don't know what and how to search anymore :-( Any ideas, or better any solution?

Comment: `load()` doe not do what you think it does here. It's just a location for clients to get JavaScript functions from. You should not be basing your production processing on server JavaScript processing. It was a "stopgap" and not an ongoing solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `system.js` collection to store javascript that runs on the mongod server.  It acts like a normal collection, so you can add functions like this:

```
db.system.js.save(
{
    _id:"helloWorldFunction",
    value: function() { return "Hello World!"}
}
```

In order to run the script, you should call `db.loadServerScripts();` and then you can use your stored functions

```
> db.loadServerScripts();
> helloWorldFunction()
Hello World!
```

For more information on this, you can check the [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) on the topic.

Comment: As far as I see I will have to insert the functions everytime I start the server. Or do you know whether I can automate this? Thank you for your reply first of all.

Comment: From what I can find, there isn't a way to specify a javascript file to run on mongod startup.  The mongo (shell) startup can take a javascript file as a parameter, so you could start mongod and create a script to run mongo after the server is up and running.